# C# Jwt Token created in one api, returns invalid_token when used in another api

Tags: c#, api, jwt

So I'm having trouble with my jwt, I'm creating a jwt in one c# api, api #1, and then using it in another c# api, api #2, both are setup in the same way the using a same secret key and issuer. When ever I try authenticating using jwt in api #1 it works fine, when used in api #2 it replies invalid_token with no other information.

Api #1
Startup.cs

```
     public static string JwtIssuer { get; private set; }
        public static string JwtKey { get; private set; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            GrpcEnvironment.SetLogger(new ConsoleLogger());
            Configuration = configuration;

            var operatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion;
            var bucketNameBase = "thinkware-snapshot-store-";

            if (operatingSystem.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
            {
                Configuration["URI"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("URI");
                Configuration["GCP_STORAGE_CRED"] = SetupSnapshotStorageCredentialsForUnix();
                Configuration["GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"] = bucketNameBase + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_STORAGE_NAMESPACE_ID");
                //Configuration["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = SetupSnapshotStorageCredentialsForUnix();
                Configuration["GCP_DATASTORE_CRED_PROJECT_ID"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_DATASTORE_CRED_PROJECT_ID");
                Configuration["GCP_STORAGE_NAMESPACE_ID"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_STORAGE_NAMESPACE_ID");
                JwtIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer");
                JwtKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey");
                Configuration["ApiKey"]=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApiKey");
            }
            else
            {
                Configuration["URI"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("URI", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                Configuration["GCP_STORAGE_CRED"] = SetupSnapshotStorageCredentialsForWindows();
                Configuration["GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"] = bucketNameBase + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_STORAGE_NAMESPACE_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                //Configuration["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=  SetupSnapshotStorageCredentialsForWindows();
                Configuration["GCP_DATASTORE_CRED_PROJECT_ID"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_DATASTORE_CRED_PROJECT_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                Configuration["GCP_STORAGE_NAMESPACE_ID"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCP_STORAGE_NAMESPACE_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                JwtIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                JwtKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                Configuration["ApiKey"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApiKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
            }

            Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"] = JwtIssuer;
            Configuration["Jwt:Key"] = JwtKey;
        }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {

                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "ThinkWare", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme { In = "header", Description = "Please enter JWT with Bearer into field", Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey" });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "Bearer", new string[] { } },
                });


            });
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
            services.AddTransient<IAuthentication, Authentication>();
            services.AddTransient<IApiKeyApproval, ApiKeyApproval>();
            services.AddTransient<ISerializer, Serializer>();
            services.AddTransient<ISnapShotBucket, SnapShotBucket>();
        }
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "ThinkWarePolicy";
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                c.DocumentTitle = "Title Documentation";
                c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
            }
            );
            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    var exception = errorFeature.Error;

                    // the IsTrusted() extension method doesn't exist and
                    // you should implement your own as you may want to interpret it differently
                    // i.e. based on the current principal
                    var errorDetail = exception.Demystify().ToString();


                    var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
                    {
                        Instance = $"urn:myorganization:error:{Guid.NewGuid()}"
                    };



                    problemDetails.Title = "An unexpected error occurred!";
                    problemDetails.Status = 500;
                    problemDetails.Detail = exception.Demystify().ToString();


                    // log the exception etc..

                    context.Response.StatusCode = problemDetails.Status.Value;
                    context.Response.WriteJson(problemDetails, "application/problem+json");
                });
            });
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Api #1 jwttoken creator

```
 private string GenerateJSONWebToken()
        {
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);


            var claims = new[] {

                new Claim("ApiKey", _config["ApiKey"])
            };
            var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                signingCredentials: credentials
            );

            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);


            return tokenString;
        }
```

Api #2 Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            Configuration = configuration;
            Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"] =
                Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix ?
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer") :
                    "https://localhost:5001/";
            Configuration["Jwt:Key"] = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix ?
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey") :
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine); ;

        }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                 {
                     options.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidateIssuer = true,
                         ValidateAudience = true,
                         ValidateLifetime = true,
                         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                         ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                         ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                     };
                 });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {

                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "ThinkWare", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme { In = "header", Description = "Please enter JWT with Bearer into field", Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey" });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "Bearer", new string[] { } },
                });


            });
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                c.DocumentTitle = "Title Documentation";
                c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
            }
            );
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

Api #2 Controller

```
private static ISnapshotBucket _SnapshotBucket { get; set; }
        private static IApiKeyApproval _apiKeyApproval;
        public PayrollEngineController(ISnapshotBucket snapshotBucket, IApiKeyApproval apiKeyApproval)
        {
            _SnapshotBucket = snapshotBucket;
            _apiKeyApproval = apiKeyApproval;
        }

        // POST: api/Engine
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Post([FromBody] PayrollRequest payrollRequest)
        {
            if (_apiKeyApproval.Approval(User.FindFirst("ApiKey")?.Value))
            {
                var download = _SnapshotBucket.DownloadSnapshot(payrollRequest.snapshot_id);
                download.Wait();






                return StatusCode(200);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(401);
            }
        }

        // GET: api/Engine
        [HttpGet]
       [AllowAnonymous]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Payroll engine GET response" };
        }
```

Comment: You're setting the audience of the token to be the same as the issuer. Is your second api also the same address as the issuer?

Comment: I only recently added the options.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];, after the problem was the already happen. Unless your talking a ValidIssuer and ValidAudiance cause i've seen on most example use the same values in both. Your second question both use the same environment variables. Or are you asking if the apis actual address is the same as the ValidIssuer because I've tried making the issuer the same address as the second api

Comment: The audience is an address that is permitted access with a given token. An issuer is an address that grants the token. It seems like API 1 is issuing the token, and it's address should be the value for the ValidIssuer. In order for API 2 to have access, it's address should be included as a valid audience.

Comment: So it tried adding two audiences when I generate the the token, do it i need to add them to startup?

Comment: @JonathonChase do you have any advice now?

Comment: You would add both audiences at token creation, and at startup you would add just the audience that is the service that will be consuming the token. The issuer should be the service that the token is receive from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203490/discussion-between-jacob-green-and-jonathon-chase).